# Keycloak : Single Logout(SLO)

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, keycloak

I am using Keycloak as the OP of a single sign-on(SSO) platform. I already connected two of my web applications to Keycloak for the single sign on function to work.

Also, I have already made one app when logging out will be redirected to Keycloak authentication server. But I want my other app to also logout when the first one logs out(SLO function). What configurations do I have to do for my 2nd app to make this happen?

Thank you for your help =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make the single logout to work, it seems that you just have to set the URL of your web app in the Admin URL(inside Keycloak command console, under Clients).

Comment: Take note that the Admin URL is only a thing on OpenID Connect clients, SAML clients do not have that option

Comment: @stephen do saml client have that option? I'm trying to use an AP-initiated logout but I don't see any requests being made to the relying party even with front channel=true setting

Comment: On the SAML client under `Fine Grain SAML Endpoint Configuration`. For front channel set the url at: `Logout Service Redirect Binding URL`, for back channel: `Logout Service POST Binding URL`